# requestAccessToEntityType - once or every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[UpdateManager sharedUpdateManager] eventStore];

if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
{
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)...
```

I want to ask the user for permission to add an event to his calendar. After it's granted do I need to ask for permission again when I want for example to remove an event (in another session after the app was closed and reopened) or is it just a want time thing?

If it's a one time thing, can I just put it in ViewDidLoad at first lunch just to "get rid of it" ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You only need to call it once:

```
BOOL needsToRequestAccessToEventStore = NO; // iOS 5 behavior
EKAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized; // iOS 5 behavior
if ([[EKEventStore class] respondsToSelector:@selector(authorizationStatusForEntityType:)]) {
    authorizationStatus = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    needsToRequestAccessToEventStore = (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined);
}

if (needsToRequestAccessToEventStore) {
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {            
        if (granted) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // You can use the event store now
            });
        }
    }];
} else if (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // You can use the event store now
} else {
    // Access denied
}
```

You shouldn't do that on the first launch, though. Only request access when you need it and that isn't the case just until the user decides to add an event.

Comment: Do I need to see the prompt on iOS 6 simulator after this ? Because right now I don't and my privacy under calendar is empty

Comment: @Sha It's normal. Privacy alerts are not displayed in iPhone simulator. Test on an actual device.

Comment: I don't have an ios 6 device handy. Why would they put a privacy section in the simulator that reads "Applications that have requested access to your calendars will appear here" ? feels wrong

Comment: `No privacy alerts are displayed in iOS Simulator for apps that access Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders.` - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

Comment: For iOS6 you need to check EKAuthorizationStatus for EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized before you can start using the event store in the else {}, just in case it is restricted or rejected.

Comment: It's wrong say, that the iPhone simulator can't display privacy alerts.  The iPhone simulator can display privacy alerts, for example reminders without problem.

Comment: I have similar question and I dont want to ask new question for the same because people always vote my questiosn down. Question 1: I can see the alert `Permission to access Calendar` only when the `authorizationStatus` is `NotDetermined`. What should we do when the `authorizationStatus` is something else like `Denied` or `Restricted`. I am trying to show the same alert again but it doesnt show at all. What can be the reason ? Question 2: When I go to setting app from my application then my application is getting crashed without any crash logs. Any suggestion would be great help. Thanks